# Search for names with particular starting in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

I have a json object like shown below which contains  id-to name mappings:

```
   idToNamesMap =  {"1":"name5","2":"name6","3":"name7","4":"name8"}
```

Now I want to search for names in this id-to name mappings object. For example search & return all names starting with string "name" along with corresponding ids. Could you suggest how to do this ?

---

I use jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to filter the items starting with `"name"` and then flip the object keys / values:

```
var idToNamesMap =  {"1":"name5","2":"name6","3":"name7","4":"name8"},
searchPattern = /^name/;

function searchMap(map, pattern)
{
    var res = {};

    $.each(map, function(i, name) {
        if (pattern.test(name)) {
            res[name] = i;
        }
    });

    return res;
}

console.log(searchMap(idToNamesMap, searchPattern));
```

Output:

```
{"name5": "1", "name6": "2", "name7": "3", "name8": "4"}
```

See also: [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: thanks could you please also clarify how to specify the pattern to search using a variable instead of just directly specifying in the code ?

Comment: @user01 Updated, does it make more sense now?

Comment: yes, definitely.. just one more thing..wanted to clarify from you what does name variable hold ?(that is a bit confusing)

Comment: @user01 Basically it contains the value of each property of `idToNamesMap` (which is what `$.each()` does), I've just called it `name` because of how you named the object :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way. It provides you a way to search for the entries with regular expressions:

```
var idToNamesMap =  {"1":"name5","2":"name6","3":"name7","4":"name8"};

idToNamesMap.search = function( pattern ) {
    var result = {};
    for ( var k in this ) {
        if ( 'function' != typeof this[ k ] ) {
            if ( this[ k ].test( pattern ) ) {
                result[ k ] = this[ k ];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log( idToNamesMap.search( /^name/ ) );​
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XaWqd/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var newObject = {};

for (key in idToNamesMap) {
    if (idToNamesMap[key].substring(0,4)=='name') 
       newObject[idToNamesMap[key]] = key;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZSEwJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

## Sample Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jarr = {'a':'one', 'b':'two', 'c':'3'}
    $.each(jarr, function(key, value){
        if((/^one/).test(value)){
            alert(key + ' -> ' + value);
        }
    });
});​
```

## Working Fiddle

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGBwb/)

## Options

There are 3 options that you can use to achieve this.

1. Use a simple regex (as above):

   `var match = /^name/.test(myString);`
2. Use `indexOf` method:

   `var match = string.length => 7 && string.indexOf("name") == 0;`
3. Use the `substring` method:

   `var match = string.length => 7 && string.substr(0, 4) == "name";`